How to verify a scheme is a fibre product


Above is one proposition that I found in Wedhorn& Görtz's Algebraic Geometry I in page 103. I do not understand two parts: 

(1) He uses the assumption II that the induced maps on stalk at any points are isomorphisms to conclude that the schemes $(X',\mathscr O_{X'})\cong (f(X'),\mathscr O_{X|f(X')})$ is isomorphism. I know if the induced maps on stalks are isomorphism at any points then the sheaves are isomorphic but how to show the underlying topological spaces are homeomorphic? I think it has something to do with the assumption that $f$ can be decomposed into homeomorphisms onto it image. But I do not have any ideas. I do not even know if $f(X')$ is open in $X$.

(2) The author claims that $(p^{-1}(f(X')),\mathscr O_{Z|p^{-1}(f(X'))})$ is the fibre product. I know why $p^{-1}(f(X'))$ should be fibre product as topological spaces but I do not know how to check why $\mathscr O_{Z|p^{-1}(f(X'))}$ is the right sheaf that we want to put on such that the whole diagram becomes not only the fibre product as topological spaces but also as schemes.

Sorry. I am currently selfstudying the book and maybe I do not have a good understanding now.  Let me reformulate my second question, in general, if we want to show $(Z,\mathscr O_Z)$ is the fibre product of the schemes $f:(X,\mathscr O_X)\rightarrow (S,\mathscr O_S)$ and $g:(Y,\mathscr O_Y)\rightarrow (S,\mathscr O_S)$, what should we do? I know how to check if $Z$ is the fibre product of underlying topological spaces of $f:X\rightarrow S$ and $g:Y\rightarrow S$, but in the category of SCHEMES every object is a topological space with an associated sheaf. There is more things to be checked ?

Can we choose arbitrary topological space which satisfies the fibre product property in category of TOP then choose any arbitrary sheaf on it? I do not think so because at least on the level of stalk the diagram has to commute. Are there more things need to be verified?

It is not true that in general the topological space of a fibered product of schemes is the fibered product of the topological spaces.
